# Import C++ library that hasn't .dll or .lib files inside

Tags: c++, dll, lib

So I have two examples of these libraries for printing nice tables. [First](https://github.com/seleznevae/libfort/tree/v0.4.2) and [second](https://github.com/dattanchu/bprinter).

I've watched MANY videos on "How to install/include/import a library into your C++ project" and each one talks about changing Visual Studio solution properties like `C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`, `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories` and finally `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`, which should contain paths to `.h/.hpp` or `.dll/.lib` files respectively.

So as we can see we **don't** have any of these files in the two libraries above.
Hence the question. How do I work with such libraries in my cpp project? I just need direct instructions or something because I don't think I'll ever understand otherwise. I am trying to install some c++ library for the first time.

Addition: **I don't want to use any package managers**.

Comment: Are you talking about a header-only library?  Then just setting the include path is sufficient.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry, I didn't see your comment for some reason. I have already solved my problem and thanks for the term "header-only library". It's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libfort` has a README.md that describes how to integrate it with your project (a step that does not actually *require* prior compilation, as it is not a "lib" but merely some additional source files to be added to your project directly).

`bprinter` requires prior compilation / installation, and comes with a `CMakeLists.txt` configuration to do this. You'll need [CMake](https://cmake.org) to do it, but it makes things really simple for you. Check its documentation.

---

`*.dll` and `*.lib` are *binary* files *compiled* from the source you check out from a source repository. They are not *supposed* to be provided from a GitHub repo. Prior to *using* a compiled library in the way you described (by making the necessary adjustments in *your project's* VS configuration), you need to *compile and install* the library according to *that project's* documentation (as with `bprinter`).

Comment: Thank you very much for such good answer. This really clarified some points for me. But I have another question: I tried to integrate the `libfort` according to the instructions in the `README.md`, but I got an error. So, to do this correctly, I need to add the `fort.hpp` and `fort.c` files to the location where the `.sln` file is located?

Comment: @Sorruss "An error" is not really enough to tell. Generally speaking, regardless of the development environment -- from VisualStudio to the command line -- you need to either put source files where the compiler is looking for them, or tell the compiler it should look where the source files are. If your project is very small, "everything in one directory" is enough. If the project is bigger, you should organize your source files in some way -- and there is no "One True Way" to do it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. "An error" is `Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol`. I also tried to restart Visual Studio. Hallelujah! Finally, after more than 15 hours, I found how to do it. I didn't know you had to add source files via `Source Files -> Add -> Existing Item`. Ohhh, thanks a lot again. But, for example, the `libfort` library also has a `CMakeLists.txt` file. Does this mean that some libraries can be integrated in more than one way?

Comment: @Sorruss I admit I only skimmed through either GitHub page, and did not look further than the "Integration" section on the entry page of libfort. My apologies; that library looks like it needs to be compiled as well. Sorry that my answer was not on-point on that one. And yes, if you have the source code, you could integrate a library any which way (as long as you honor the copyright license restrictions).

Comment: No. You really helped a lot and provided a lot of useful information without which it would have been very difficult. Now that I managed to integrate the `libfort` library, I'm trying to integrate `bprniter` with `cmake` as well, so far not so successful, but now I feel way more confident :). Thank you again